# Bind a key to press another key with sxhkd

Tags: xdotool, sxhkd

I recently switched over from using windows where I used to use AutoHotKey for a few temporary shortcuts and key remapping. This is a small section of the code I used:

```
d::
{ 
   sendinput, [ 
   sleep, 30
   sendinput, !o 
   sleep, 30
}
```

Pressing d would would automatically type out [, and o.
I tried to do the same on sxhkd, but pressing the d key results in nothing, no d, [ or alt+o.
Here's what I've tried:

```
d
    xdotool type --delay 30 "["
    sleep 30ms
    xdotool type --delay 30 "alt+o"
    sleep 30ms
```

I've tried a few other solutions, But none of them seem to work.
Interestingly, replacing d with a mouse button, like button1 does make the program work, however, it only types "[" and not the alt+o.

On doing this:

```
d
    notify-send "Key event: d"
```

the system does detect that the d key is pressed, But none of the above commands can be executed with keyboard keys, only mouse buttons. Help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this would be `xmodmap` I would have to look up the keysym for those keys but a simple example is `xmodmap -e  "keysym a = b"`

Comment: I don't think it's possbile to map multiple keys to one with xmodmap unfortunately

Comment: @PixelatedXenon, did you ever find a solution?